# How do I remove a subdomain from URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I followed the Railscast on adding subdomains to a Rails app, [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised), and everything is working great with the subdomains. Now I just can't figure out a way to link back to the root domain without a subdomain if the requested subdomain does not exist.

I've tried adding the following to my `application_controller.rb` file

```
redirect_to root_path(subdomain: false) if @city_or_state.nil?
```

where `@city_or_state` determines weather the requested subdomain is valid. The `redirect_to` goes back to the root, but does not remove the subdomain.

For example, if a user tries to go to `invalid.domain.com` they are redirected to the root, but subdomain is not removed.

I'm trying to get `invalid.domain.com` to redirect to `domain.com`

Comment: what version of Rails?  That was broken in 4.0.0.beta1, but is fixed in 4.0.0.rc1

Comment: I'm working on Rails 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I had to use the following: `redirect_to root_url(:host => request.domain)`

When I tried `root_path(:host => request.domain)` it didn't work. Only works with `root_url`.

I found the answer on some comments from Daniel Kehoe [here](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/issues/7)

When attempting to visit a domain that does not exist, the invalid subdomain is removed from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way i think it works!
In the application_controller.rb you can add a `before_filter :validate_subdomain`
Then you add this code to the controller:

```
private 
def validate_subdomain
   # @city_or_state must be initialized before this 
  if @city_or_state.nil?
   redirect_to request.domain
  end
end
```

Comment: @akjoe Did it worked? I didn't test it because for that i have to configure subdomains in local machine, so i just did the test of redirection for the request.domain but from the domain itself.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I'm back to my desk and let you know... Thanks!

Comment: I added the 'request.domain' and tried 'blue.lvh.me:3000' (an invalid subdomain) and it just went to a blank page. I pulled this from the log though: 'Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-30 12:40:14 -0800
  Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."subdomain" = 'Blue' LIMIT 1
  State Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."subdomain" = 'Blue' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://blue.lvh.me:3000lvh.me'

Comment: Ok, I might have my answer... I came across this: [link](https://gist.github.com/bsodmike/1369419) and I think this is the solution